# python flask redirect to another page

Tags: python, flask

I have a login page as `login.py` which renders `login.html`. On submit i want to redirect to `mainpage.py` which renders `mainpage.html`. But on submit click it just doesn't redirect. I get a page not found error. And the url remains the same

```
@app.route('/login',methods = ['GET','POST'])
def index():
    try:
        if request.method =='POST':
            db_user = request.form['db_user']
            db_pwd = request.form['db_pwd']
            if (connect(db_user,db_pwd)==1):
                return redirect("/mainpage", code=302)
        else:
            return render_template('login.html')    
    except Exception as e:
        print(("error :", str(e)))
        return render_template('login.html')
```

What should be mentioned in the redirect option? is it the html filename or py filename where the html gets rendered? I tried with html filename,py filename and the name in the @app.route. but without success

Comment: Try adding the `else` block for db connect.

Comment: So is the redirect method correct? Should this be html file name or .py file name mentioned here?

Comment: @kten `redirect(url_for("your_function_name"))` is better, but specifying an URL, like `/mainpage` should be OK.

Comment: Should this link (/main) be defined somewhere else? other than the mainpage.py itself?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### The cause of the 404 error:

When you redirect to `/mainpage`, Flask will be looking for a route handler in your `login.py` file, not `mainpage.py`. Since `login.py` doesn't have a route handler for `/mainpage`, it gives you a 404. It never reaches `mainpage.py`.

#### What you are trying to do and possible solutions:

What you are trying to do is separating your routes across different files. For that, you need to explicitly *tell* Flask where your route handlers are (in other words, in which files it should look for route handlers).

There are two ways for doing that:

1. See this documentation ([Larger Applications](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/patterns/packages/)) to learn how to organize your files as a package. You'll have to import mainpage.py into login.py, or vice-versa.
2. Or use a blueprint: [Modular Applications with Blueprints](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/blueprints/#blueprints).

> Please note that you'll only need that if your application has a substantial size. If you have just a few route handlers, you should probably keep it simple with everything in one single file.

Comment: Thank you. this was exactly the problem. But one query. If i need to use separate files and need to import the file into the other file as mentioned. Does the file have to be defined as a class? Or is it possible to import after it is defined as packages?

Comment: I believe both package and module should work, but [Flask documentation](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/patterns/packages/) suggests using a package: "it’s a good idea to use a package instead of a module".

Answer (score 1):

The first parameter of [`redirect`](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/api/#flask.redirect) is the url which you want the client redirected to. You can hard code the url as the first parameter. And also you can use [`url_for`](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/api/#flask.url_for) to generate the url for the given endpoint.

For example:

```
@app.route("/url")
def endpoint():
    return "Test redirect & url_for"
```

You can use `redirect(url_for("endpoint"))` or `redirect("/url")` to redirect to `/url`

And the [Quickstart](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/quickstart/) point the advantages of use `url_for` instead of hard code the url.